# How can I apply SmartyStreets validation to two forms in the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, smartystreets

```
.col-md-6
%h3 US Address

%form.form-horizontal
%label Street Address
%input.form-control{id: 'street', name: 'street', style: 'margin-bottom: 10px;font-size:13px;height:30px"'}

%label City
%input.form-control{id: 'city', name: 'city', style: 'margin-bottom: 10px;font-size:13px;height:30px"'}

%label State
%input.form-control{id: 'state', name: 'state', style: 'margin-bottom: 10px;font-size:13px;height:30px"'}

%label ZIP Code
%input.form-control{id: 'zipcode', name: 'zipcode', style: 'margin-bottom: 10px;font-size:13px;height:30px"'}

.row
  %br
  %br
  %input.btn.btn-ss-alt.btn-lg{type: "submit", name: "commit", style: "margin-bottom:20px;float:right;margin-right: 15px;padding:10px 72px;"}

.col-md-6
%h3 International Address

%form.form-horizontal
%label Street Address
%input.form-control{id: 'street', name: 'street', style: 'margin-bottom: 10px;font-size:13px;height:30px"'}

%label City
%input.form-control{id: 'city', name: 'city', style: 'margin-bottom: 10px;font-size:13px;height:30px"'}

%label State
%input.form-control{id: 'state', name: 'state', style: 'margin-bottom: 10px;font-size:13px;height:30px"'}

%label ZIP Code
%input.form-control{id: 'zipcode', name: 'zipcode', style: 'margin-bottom: 10px;font-size:13px;height:30px"'}

.row
  %br
  %br
  %input.btn.btn-ss-alt.btn-lg{type: "submit", name: "commit", style: "margin-bottom:20px;float:right;margin-right: 15px;padding:10px 72px;"}
```

The SmartyStreets plugin is only applying to the first form, no the second.

`var liveaddress = $.LiveAddress({
  key: #{ENV['SMARTY_STREETS']},
  debug: true,
  addresses: [{
    street: '#street',
    city: '#city',
    state: '#state',
    zipcode: '#zipcode'
  }]
 });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, just wrap each form within a form tag and assign a distinct name (or id) to each field.  The plugin will pick it up.  Here's an example with two forms using custom field mapping:

http://jsfiddle.net/p02qxh0L/69/

Here is an example with 16 forms on the same page using auto-mapping:

https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugin/examples

Example HTML:

```
    <form id="shipping">
    <input type="text" id="pais" name="pais" placeholder="pais">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="calle" name="calle" placeholder="calle">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" placeholder="ciudad">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="estado" name="estado" placeholder="estado">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="codigo" name="codigo" placeholder="codigo">
    <br>
</form>
<hr>
<form id="billing">
    <input type="text" id="pais2" name="pais2" placeholder="pais2">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="calle2" name="calle2" placeholder="calle2">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="ciudad2" name="ciudad2" placeholder="ciudad2">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="estado2" name="estado2" placeholder="estado2">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="codigo2" name="codigo2" placeholder="codigo2">
    <br>
</form>
```

Example Javascript

```
    evar ss = jQuery.LiveAddress({
    key: '5640108848371823003',
    waitForStreet: true, 
    debug: true,
    addresses: [{
        country: '#pais',
        street: '#calle',
        city: '#ciudad',
        state: '#estado',
        zipcode: '#codigo'
    },{
        country: '#pais2',
        street: '#calle2',
        city: '#ciudad2',
        state: '#estado2',
        zipcode: '#codigo2'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Setting one more address object inside the `addresses` array was the ticket. Thanks!

Comment: If I set more than one address object in the addresses array , then is it necessary to provide addresses to both fields?